# How can I fix "you do not have permission to mount this file" error in Windows 8.1 Enterprise?

Tags: windows-8.1, file-permissions

I receive this error whenever I attempt to mount a disc image (iso) under Windows 8.1 Enterprise using the right-click context menu. So far I have tried:

- run explorer elevated (couldn't make it happen)
- uninstall all other apps that may possibly mount iso (didn't help)
- take ownership of the file (also didn't help)

I am somewhat fundamentally confused; is this a permissions issue or a software conflict?

EDIT:

Oddly enough, the mount succeeds. The drive shows up. What in the world does the error mean then?

Comment: Is the ISO image on a network share?

Comment: nope it sure isnt

Comment: I have the same problem. Gives the error message but then mounts the ISO file.

Comment: I have moved drive letters around, logged in as various users w/ various rights, changed ownership, file names, put it on external, sourced it internally on a non-boot drive, put it on the SSD boot drive...all of it. Same problem. Funny, I didn't even realize it was mounting it when the error message popped up until I read this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mount is prevented by aa filesystem attribute called sparse. FAR commander (a norton commander clone) can remove this.

Answer (score 3):

This is usually an indication that the drive letter that it's attempting to mount the ISO to is not available.  It then tries the next available drive letter.  The message itself is misleading.

If you really want the message to go away, try changing the drive letters of any external drives or mapped drives you're using.

Answer (score 0):

simply rename the file (file.iso > file-1.iso > file.iso)
there is a funky bug in explorer

see http://www.thewindowsplanet.com/2042/you-dont-have-permission-to-mount-the-file-error-when-mounting-iso-image-in-windows-8.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the ISO file to a new file by saving it to a different folder or giving it a different name. To do this, you might have to restart the system.

If this doesn't work, try to mount the ISO file using the PowerShell.

Example 1: Mounting an ISO

```
PS C:\>Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "E:\ISO-Files\My US Visit Fall 2010 Pictures.iso"
```

Example 2: Dismount a disk image by path

```
PS C:\>Dismount-DiskImage -ImagePath "E:\ISO-Files\My US Visit Fall 2010 Pictures.iso"
```

Example 3: Dismount a disk image by device path

```
PS C:\>Dismount-DiskImage -DevicePath \\.\CDROM1
```

---

Reference
 1. [Get-DiskImage - Gets one or more disk image objects (virtual hard disk or ISO)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-diskimage?view=win10-ps)
 2. [Mount-DiskImage - Mounts a previously created disk image (virtual hard disk or ISO), making it appear as a normal disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/mount-diskimage?view=win10-ps)
 3. [Dismount-DiskImage - Dismounts a disk image (virtual hard disk or ISO) so that it can no longer be accessed as a disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/dismount-diskimage?view=win10-ps)